# Asyntask doInbackground android not working properly

Tags: android, android-asynctask, hashmap

I used an asynctask to load some data from web by using Json method
I call the Asyctask by using this code (`new LoadAllMyOrderItems().execute();`) in oncreate method
i try the same code for other activity and it works
but for this activity same code doesnt work!!!

i put some log to see what is going on in backgroung

here it is
i declared MyorderItemList

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyOrderItemList=null;
```

[image]

as i mentioned in photo i dont know why that logdidnt show and error occure!!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `MyOrderItemList` is `null`. You need to create it first with

```
MyOrderItemList = new ArrayList();
```

Comment: i already declare it    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyOrderItemList=null;

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to put this line of code in oncreate method
    MyOrderItemList = new ArrayList< HashMap < String , String > > ( ) ;